# How much of a bad practice is it to get out of nested functions with an exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception

My question concerns exceptions in Python and what a good-practice use of them would be. I have a GUI application, where some code runs as a separate thread (so the GUI doesn't freeze). Then I have a button that is supposed to cut off the operation.

The threaded code is made of several nested functions, and getting "out" of them would be quite a hassle (basically several times: force a return, handle the return, etc.), so I thought I might just use an exception, handle it as the closing argument of the thread and return to the GUI. But something tells me that's really bad programming practice. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you show some pseudo code?

Comment: For cancellation? I think it’s fine. That’s just an opinion, though. :) (Definitely make sure to give it its own type.)

Comment: Python uses exceptions for this kind of thing all over. In particular, every generator is terminated by throwing `StopException`.

Comment: @Amadan: A lot of the things Python uses exceptions for, including `StopIteration`, actually cause a lot of trouble, though :P (`KeyboardInterrupt` might be the least troublesome, and also a good parallel to this.)

Comment: @Ry- If you are refering to unrestricted `except`, that's programmers' fault. If not, can you elaborate on what the "trouble" is?

Comment: @Amadan: Stuff like `AttributeError` catching hiding mistakes in `__getattr__`, and to a lesser extent (especially since PEP 479) `StopIteration` catching hiding mistakes in unrelated functions (`next()` called somewhere in a `__next__`).

Comment: @Ry- Ah I see what you mean. Definitely tricky. However, that's where Python is — these mechanisms are so ingrained into Python that trying to avoid using them is kind futile.

Comment: It is close to a matter of taste. But IMHO the good question is *which way (exception or not) giver the clearer and easier to read code*. If you want to write *Pythonic* code, readability should be one of the most important concerns.

Comment: thank you for the answers, I think I'll go with a custom exception - it should yield vastly better code from a readability standpoint, and I'm not trying to cover up any bad coding, just avoid dealing with a big number of returns.